# Configuration.Properties object returning null in Visual Studio 2017 VSIX extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I built an extension for Visual Studio 2015 using a VSIX project template. It adds a button in the context menu when you right click on a project in the solution explorer. When you click on this button, it changes some of the debugging settings for that project so that it is ready to debug.

However, I also need to make it compatible with Visual Studio 2017. Everything seems to work fine in terms of the button appearing in the menu. I use the dte2 object to get the currently selected items and then I use that to get the selected project. From that I get the active configuration and use that to change the properties of the project.

Everything works fine up until I get the configuration object. I can get the object, but when I try to get configuration.properties, it returns back null.

```
DTE2 dte2 = (DTE2)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE));
SelectedItem selectedItem = dte2.SelectedItems.Item(1);
Project project = selectedItem.Project;

Configuration configuration = project.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration;
string path = configuration.Properties.Item("OutputPath").value.ToString();
```

Everything works fine up until I try to get the Properties from configuration. It returns null, so I am getting an error when I use .Item().

This same code worked for me in Visual Studio 2015, but it isn't working in Visual Studio 2017. Does anyone know any solutions or work arounds to this?

[This](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/5500/configurationmanageractiveconfigurationproperties.html) is the only related link I found after quite a bit of google research. But here the only response from the visual studio team is that they don't have enough information.

**EDIT:**
This is what I ended up working for me:

```
DTE2 dte2 = (DTE2)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE));
SelectedItem selectedItem = dte2.SelectedItems.Item(1);
Project project = selectedItem.Project;

VCProject vcproj = project.Object as VCProject;
VCConfiguration vcconfig = vcproj.ActiveConfiguration;
VCDebugSettings vcdebug = vcconfig.DebugSettings as VCDebugSettings;
```

Then the VCDebugSettings object can edit the debug properties of the project. The available properties can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcdebugsettings.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know any solutions or work arounds to this?

If your project is c++ project, you can use VCProject to get the configuration object. like this:

```
 private void GetProjectProperties(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DTE2 dte = (DTE2)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE));
            VCProject prj = dte.Solution.Projects.Item(1).Object as VCProject;
            foreach (VCConfiguration vccon in prj.Configurations)
            {
                IVCRulePropertyStorage generalRule = vccon.Rules.Item("ConfigurationGeneral");

                string outputPath = vccon.OutputDirectory;

                vccon.OutputDirectory = "$(test)";
                //string test1 = generalRule.GetEvaluatedPropertyValue(2);
                string tar = generalRule.GetEvaluatedPropertyValue("TargetExt");
                string name = generalRule.GetEvaluatedPropertyValue("TargetName");
            }
}
```

Comment: What are you using to include the VCProject object. I did a google search and it said to use the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProject` namespace, but it keeps giving me an error that it can't find it.

Comment: I figured out the namespace part. I had to add a reference to my project before using the namespace. But my next question is, is there a way to get a list of all of the properties that are available through `generalRule.GetEvaluatedPropertyValue()`?

Comment: I try to research related document, it seems that it no way to get a list of all of the properties. I have check the API, it seems that it has not related property to list the project properties.

Comment: @stevensvs5 I am using VS2017 and I have installed the VisualStudio SDK as part of the installation but still I cannot find Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.dll in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies.
Can you please tell me how you obtained the dll?

Comment: This is how I did it: In the solution explorer, there is a item named References. Right click on that and select Add Reference. Then under Assemblies > Extensions there will be Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine. Check that and click okay. Then you can include it in your file and use it.